# C++ Filling a Char Array with Multiple Strings and Floats

Tags: c++

```
char msg[40]; 
string s = "The price is $"; 
float price = 120.00; 
string input = " and the tax is $";  
float tax = 5.00;
```

For example, I want to fill msg with "The price is $120.00 dollars and the tax is $5.00". The code I have so far that is not working is:

```
msg = s + price + input + tax;
```

I am stuck right now and can't figure it out, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should declare `msg` as a `std::string`.

Then you can either use `stringstream` to convert the float to string or with C++11, you can use the function `std::to_string(arg)` with various supported types for `arg`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the c-function `sprintf` (unless you want to use a c++ string, in which case `stringstream` is an easy option.

This can be done by

```
sprintf(msg, "The price is $%.2f and the tax is $%.2f", price, tax);
```

There is a good description of the `printf` syntax [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Comment: Didn't know this function existed. It is easy to use and got rid of my errors, thanks for the help.